# Java: NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the String to int with Integer.parseInt(simNumber) but I am getting the error bleow. How can I convert a String to int? I searched in the Internet and found this way with Integer.pareInt(simNumber).

I appreciate any help.

**Code**

```
byte[] simNumberArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 17, i);
String simNumber = new String(simNumberArray, "UTF-8"); // 13534035454
int simNr = Integer.parseInt(simNumber); //The error appears at this line.
this.record.setSimCardNumber(simNr);
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "13534035454"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.ShenzhenDecoder.decode(ShenzhenDecoder.java:59)
    at org.ShenzhenTest.main(ShenzhenTest.java:22)
```

Comment: integer values has to be within a range please see the documentation

Comment: Please don't downvote on the grounds of obviousness. This question is well-written, has a code snippet, and an error output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

int is not enough for this, try long type

you should also check this: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 3):

"13534035454" is too big to fit into a 32 bit `int`. (The largest possible value is 2147483647.)

You ought to attempt to convert to a `long`, which is 64 bit and allows values up to the *much* larger 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers posted, the range is enough for int and you can long.

In other note,  suggest you not to take the Phone number as integer instead use as it is (String).

Because the numbers we need generally when arithmetic operations are required like total, average etc.